# How to connect membrane tracks on a keyboard? Problem on photo

Tags: pcb, connector, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers, keyboard

How to connect membrane tracks on a keyboard?
[image: A keyboard matrix and a pcb]

[image]

Comment: I am assuming the "membrane tracks" are conductive on the bottom side? You could take a piece of stiff plastic strip and drill holes so that it can sandwich the membrane and the PCB.

Comment: why don't you examine how the connection was accomplished in the keyboard assembly?

Answer (score 2):

You may use one of the [conductive adhesives](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/glue-adhesives-applicators/909?s=N4IgTCBcDaIMYHsB2ATArnALgSwG4FMACAcwBs18QBdAXyA).

Answer (score 1):

Zebra strips could be good here, you'd need to find a way to maintain pressure on them though.

Answer (score 0):

put two layers of foam tape, or a strip of silicone rubber, on top of the plastic then clamp the two parts together using flat pieces of something rigid.